# My syscall cause segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm writing a simple syscall based on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/anubhav-shrimal/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-dad32875872), and boot into the new kernel with my syscall in it, but when I compile a test, and execute it, it cause segmentation fault (core dumped).
My my_syscall.h (hello.c equivalent in the tutorial) looks like this.

```
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/kernel.h> 
#include <linux/sched.h>  
#include <asm/current.h>

struct smallStruct {
    int integer;
    char str[20];
};

struct bigStruct {
    long id;
    struct smallStruct a;
    struct smallStruct b;
    struct smallStruct c;
};

asmlinkage long test_syscall(int pid, struct bigStruct *info)
{
    info->id = pid;

    info->a.integer = 0;
    info->a.str[0] = 'A';
    info->a.str[1] = '\0';

    info->b.integer = 1;
    info->b.str[0] = 'B';
    info->b.str[1] = '\0';

    info->c.integer = 2;
    info->c.str[0] = 'C';
    info->c.str[1] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

I actually try to write a syscall that get some information and store back into `*info`, and I need the `str` in the `smallStruct`, but everytime I try to modify the `str`, it cause  segmentation fault (core dumped), and when I remove those modification to the `str` to temporarily avoid core dump, it still doesn't work as I expected. This is what my test file looks like:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct smallStruct
{
    int integer;
    char str[20];
};

struct bigStruct
{
    long id;
    struct smallStruct a;
    struct smallStruct b;
    struct smallStruct c;
};

int main()
{
    long sys_return_value;
    struct bigStruct info;
    sys_return_value = syscall(548, 1, &info);
    printf("id = %ld, return %ld\n", info.id, sys_return_value);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the `info` in my test isn't modified by the syscall at all.
I even use `printk` in the my_syscall.h and the `pid` I pass to my syscall isn't correct at all. this is what the `printk` print in `dmesg`

[image: this is what the <code>printk</code> print in <code>dmesg</code>]

The `id` in my_syscall is supposed to be the `pid`, and it is passed in my test with the value of 1. (`syscall(548, 1, &info);`)

I know it is quite long, but I would be grateful if anyone can explain what is wrong with my implement,
Thank you.

Comment: Do not post text as pictures.

Comment: Take a look at how existing syscalls handle user pointers.

Comment: to represent processes id (which is pid I guess?) you can use `p_id` data type. It translates to integer, not `long`

Comment: Look into `copy_to_user`.

Comment: What exactly are you printk'ing in your test?  Please post the same code you are using for the test.

Comment: @roim Yes, but I cannot pass the value from the ```syscall(548,1,&info)``` to the syscall function, you can see that I print the value of ```pid``` through the ```info->id```.
@nate-eldredge I print fields of the ```bigStruct```.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765421/634919 for another possible issue that could explain why the `pid` parameter is wrong.  Note the importance of the `SYSCALL_DEFINEx` macros.  It appears your tutorial is inaccurate or incomplete (the issue doesn't affect their example because their system call takes no arguments).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a user pointer that is part of the part of the process stack to the kernel. This is bad practice and will never work because kernel memory and user memory are separate entities. You need to use System Apis to pass pointer to and from user to kernel memory. Look at copy_to_user and copy_from_user functions. You can also put ioctl method into use which creates a backdoor between user/application and kernel

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'll try that, and I'm really grateful for your help, I hope you have a nice day ^^

Comment: Can you explain why the "syscall(548, 1, &info);" the ```pid``` I get is supposed to be 1, but when I ```printk``` on ```dmesg```, it has random value like in the picture, please? I see many people do that and they successfully pass the value.